# How to know on what page number flowable was placed during rendering a pdf with reportlab

Tags: python, pdf, reportlab

How to determine on what page(need a page number) will be each flowable after rendering to pdf. I was thinking to add a custom id attribute  to flowable, so i will know what flowable is it. But how can i determine on what page it will be placed?
What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended with following solution. Addeda an custom id flo_id to every flowable. And override method handle_flowable in BaseDocTemplate, where was checking and saving id,

```
class SignDocTemplate(BaseDocTemplate):
   blocks_to_pages = {}
   def handle_flowable(self, flowables):
     f = flowables[0]
     BaseDocTemplate.handle_flowable(self, flowables)
     if hasattr(f,'flo_id'):
       if self.blocks_to_pages.has_key(self.canv._pageNumber):
          self.blocks_to_pages[self.canv._pageNumber].append(f.flo_id)
       else:
          self.blocks_to_pages[self.canv._pageNumber]= [f.flo_id,]
```

And after building a doc it will be available at document instance in blocks_to_pages variable.

Answer (score 2):

At what point do you need this information?  It becomes available as the document is constructed, so you can get it after rendering by overriding methods such as `afterPage`, `afterDrawPage`, and `afterFlowable`.  You can then get the page number from the `DocTemplate` class (I believe there's a class variable called something like `_currentPage`, but you'll need to check the ReportLab code since I don't think it's documented).