# Reportlab: header with data from page

Tags: python, reportlab

I'm using the on page function and a page template to make headers for a subset of the pages in my document:

```
templates.append(PageTemplate(id='Overview', frames=frame, onPage=HeaderOverview))
```

The header function for this template:

```
################################
# Function HeaderOverview - header for overview page
def HeaderOverview(canvas,doc):
    canvas.saveState()
    headboxh = 15
    headboxx = 20
    headboxy = 730
    headboxw = 570
    canvas.rect(headboxx, headboxy, headboxw, headboxh, fill=1)  
    canvas.setFillColor(colors.black)
    canvas.setFont("Helvetica", 14)
    canvas.setFillColor(colors.white)

    canvas.drawString(headboxx + 15,headboxy+.25*headboxh,"Mathematics")
    textWidth = stringWidth("Mathematics", "Helvetica", 12) 
    canvas.setFont("Helvetica", 12)
    canvas.drawString(headboxw - 15 - textWidth,headboxy+.25*headboxh,course)

    canvas.restoreState()
```

This works great, except that the course variable that's passed (which changes with each page in the section) is the last one in the sequence, since this function's not really called until the final build (I think that's how it works). What I need is to do this so that the value is the value that's on the page. If I could draw it as I write the page itself, that'd be fine, too. Here's my attempt at that:

```
####################################################################################
# Function makeGradeOverview(course): makes Overview chart for grade
#
def makeGradeOverview(canvas, course):
    report.append(NextPageTemplate("Overview"))
    report.append(PageBreak())

    headboxh = 50
    headboxx = 20
    headboxy = 600#730
    headboxw = 540

    canvas.saveState()
    canvas.setFont("Helvetica", 12)
    textWidth = stringWidth(course, "Helvetica", 12)
    canvas.drawString(headboxw - 15 - textWidth,headboxy+.25*headboxh,course)
    canvas.restoreState()
    # put course name as title
    if len(course)<=2:
        headerrow = ''.join(['Grade ', course, ' Overview'])
    else:
        headerrow = ''.join([course, ' Overview'])
    report.append(Paragraph(headerrow, styles["Overview Title"]))

    report.append(Spacer(1, 16))

    GridInfo = []
    topics = topiclist(course)

    for topic in topics:
        report.append(Paragraph(topic, styles["Overview Sub"]))
        report.append(Spacer(1, 8))

        subtopics = subtopiclist(course, topic)

        sublist = []
        for subtopic in subtopics:
             report.append(Paragraph(''.join([r'<bullet>&bull</bullet>',subtopic]), styles["Overview Table"]))
```

This doesn't throw an error or anything, but it doesn't seem to actually draw anything, either.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: afterPage or afterDrawPage might be involved, but I'm not sure how to construct those to use info from the current page

Comment: Could you give a bit more context in regards to the `course` variable from the first attempt. How/where is it set/changed? Do you have a list containing the courses that `HeaderOverview` needs to use?

Comment: I'm looping through a set course list, calling this function each time I write a new course's page/pages. After looping through the whole list, I have a set of pages, and the course variable changes every page or every other page, to reflect the info on the page.

Comment: *by 'this function', I mean the makeGradeOverview function.

Comment: Would it be possible to create an iterable of each course that can be used for the `HeaderOverview` function?

Comment: Does that mean programmatically creating a new HeaderOverview specific to each course? That sounds workable, but I don't know how to do it - I don't want to manually create one for each course, because it needs to be flexible to future changes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's another idea...

Perhaps it would work to use specific flowables that can be identified to update the course. You can add custom attributes to flowables if necessary to help identify them (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9047171/645956) post).

For example, you might be able to do something like this:

```
...
report.append(some_content)

report.append(PageBreak())
report[-1].new_course = True  # gives that PageBreak flowable a custom attribute

report.append(some_more_content)
...
```

And set up some variables:

```
course_list = [...]
course_iter = iter(course_list)
current_course = next(course_iter)
```

Then you can check each flowable after it is rendered to see if it has that attribute and update the current course if it does.

```
def afterFlowable(flowable):
    global current_course
    if hasattr(flowable, 'new_course'):
        current_course = next(course_iter)

doc.afterFlowable = afterFlowable
```

`HeaderOverview` will be able to use the `current_course` variable to get the right course, since both `HeaderOverview` and `afterFlowable` are called at various points during the final build.

Comment: If I use it like this: doc.build(report, onFirstPage=Header, onLaterPages=HeaderOverview), then isn't it called for each page?

Comment: Programmatically? If I could do that well, I wouldn't need to try to do this in a header, but there's not a good facility in RL for calculating the vertical space taken up by text. I have something that works 85% of the time, but that's not good enough.

Comment: I need to dig into it a bit more, but I think that it has promise, so I'll accept/bounty at this point. I'll report back when I know the whole scoop here. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Alas, two issues: afterFlowable doesn't work as a function name, but after renaming, it gets run, but doesn't affect output - they're all still printed with the name of the last course in the sequence.

Comment: One thing I forgot is that `current_course` must be declared as a global variable at the start of the `afterFlowable` function (e.g. `global current_course`). I've made a simplified version using this method that seems to work after this adjustment. I'm not sure what you mean by `afterFlowable` not working as a function name (is that name already in use?). If it still doesn't get the order right, try printing anything in both the `afterFlowable` and `HeaderOverview` functions to see when each is being called. BTW, I'm removing a few of my comments to reduce mess.

Comment: That global def'n did it - in addition to the bounty, 50 internets to you, good programmer! Thanks!