# Reportlab text background size doesn't match font size

Tags: python, text, reportlab

I'm trying to have a header with white text on a simple black bar (with content from the page, so doing an actual header is way complicated). The problem is that the background of the text doesn't seem to scale with the text, as seen in my MWI:

```
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.lib.enums import TA_JUSTIFY, TA_RIGHT, TA_CENTER, TA_LEFT
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter, landscape
from reportlab.platypus import PageTemplate, Frame, NextPageTemplate, BaseDocTemplate, SimpleDocTemplate, Paragraph, Spacer, Image, Table, TableStyle, PageBreak
from reportlab.platypus import ListFlowable, ListItem
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet, ParagraphStyle
from reportlab.lib.units import inch
from reportlab.rl_config import defaultPageSize
from reportlab.pdfbase.pdfmetrics import stringWidth
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

#c = canvas.Canvas("tables.pdf")
doc = SimpleDocTemplate("mwi.pdf",pagesize=letter,
                        rightMargin=72,leftMargin=72,
                        topMargin=72,bottomMargin=60)

styles=getSampleStyleSheet()
styles.add(ParagraphStyle(name='Table Top Black Back', fontName ='Helvetica',fontSize=14, backColor = colors.black, textColor=colors.white, alignment=TA_LEFT))
styles.add(ParagraphStyle(name='Table Top Red Back', fontName ='Helvetica',fontSize=9, backColor = colors.red, textColor=colors.black, alignment=TA_LEFT))

styleN = styles["BodyText"]

# Header
# report: topic/subtopic overview
report = []
ptext = 'Test' 
report.append(Paragraph(ptext, styles["Table Top Black Back"]))
report.append(Spacer(1, 24))

ptext = 'Test' 
report.append(Paragraph(ptext, styles["Table Top Black Back"]))
report.append(Spacer(1, 24))

ptext = 'Test' 
report.append(Paragraph(ptext, styles["Table Top Red Back"]))
report.append(Spacer(1, 48))


# Build Document
doc.build(report)
```

Comment: This looks to me like a bug in ReportLab. You will probably want to report it to the developers. In the meantime, a workaround would probably be to manually draw a box behind the text of the size and color you want. Getting it to match the size of the text, of course, will be tricky, but you can probably look at the ReportLab source for ideas on how to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the info. It's always hard to tell if I just don't know enough about it or if it's a genuine bug. I'd love to draw the box myself, but I can't seem to access the canvas while not in the header. If you know how I can do that...

Comment: What information do you need from the document that this can't be done with a header? I think I have a solution, but perhaps I'm not understanding your needs

Comment: I need some data from the page - I want the grade level in the page content to be in the header, but I haven't been able to pass that info to the header. If you have a solution for that, that'd be even better!

Comment: This is a similar issue to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14913018/reportlab-header-with-data-from-page - there's a bounty there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firstly, from your code, it won't compile as it gave error.

```
ImportError: cannot import name ListFlowable
ImportError: cannot import name ListItem
```

I removed the import for these as it's not required here.

The reason why the background size does not match is because you did not specify "leading" attribute in your Paragraph, you changed your "fontSize", but did not change "leading" attribute.

What is this "leading"?
This is the spacing between adjacent lines of text; a good rule of thumb is to make this 20% larger than the point size. To get double-spaced text, use a high leading.

By default, fontSize is set at 10 and leading is set at 12.

So in your example above, as soon as you set your fontSize to 14, but your leading is still at a value of 12, that is the reason why your text does not sized well.

Solution for this is to defined a slightly larger leading in your example above.

I don't see this as a bug, but rather a not optimal design consideration. This is a very subjective topic, not sure what is going through the reportlab-developer's that time.

```
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.lib.enums import TA_JUSTIFY, TA_RIGHT, TA_CENTER, TA_LEFT
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter, landscape
from reportlab.platypus import PageTemplate, Frame, NextPageTemplate, BaseDocTemplate, SimpleDocTemplate, Paragraph, Spacer, Image, Table, TableStyle, PageBreak
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet, ParagraphStyle
from reportlab.lib.units import inch
from reportlab.rl_config import defaultPageSize
from reportlab.pdfbase.pdfmetrics import stringWidth
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

#c = canvas.Canvas("tables.pdf")
doc = SimpleDocTemplate("mwi.pdf",pagesize=letter,
                    rightMargin=72,leftMargin=72,
                    topMargin=72,bottomMargin=60)

styles=getSampleStyleSheet()
styles.add(ParagraphStyle(name='Table Top Black Back', fontName ='Helvetica',fontSize=14, leading=16,backColor = colors.black, textColor=colors.white, alignment=TA_LEFT))
styles.add(ParagraphStyle(name='Table Top Red Back', fontName ='Helvetica',fontSize=9, leading=12, backColor = colors.red, textColor=colors.black, alignment=TA_LEFT))

styleN = styles["BodyText"]

# Header
# report: topic/subtopic overview
report = []
ptext = 'Test' 
report.append(Paragraph(ptext, styles["Table Top Black Back"]))
report.append(Spacer(1, 24))

ptext = 'Test' 
report.append(Paragraph(ptext, styles["Table Top Black Back"]))
report.append(Spacer(1, 24))

ptext = 'Test' 
report.append(Paragraph(ptext, styles["Table Top Red Back"]))
report.append(Spacer(1, 48))

# Build Document
doc.build(report)
```

Hope this helps. Happy reportlab coding.