# Add Header based on Condition

Tags: python, reportlab

I'm using reportlab to generate a PDF document that has two types of reports.

Please assume reports are r1 and r2. There may be more than 2-3 pages in each report. So i want to add a header like text from second page of each report.

For example in r1 reports page add "r1 report continued..." and in the pages of 
r2 report add "r2 report continued..." How can i do that.

Currently i'm creating a list of the elements and passing it to template build function. So i cannot identify which report is being processed.

For example...

```
elements = []
elements.append(r1)
...
.....
elements.append(r2)
doc.build(elements)
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally i managed to resolve it. But i'm not sure if its a proper method.
A big thanks to [grc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/645956/grc) who provided [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15181060/3736998) answer from where i created my solution.

As in grc's answer i have created a afterFlowable callback function.

```
def afterFlowable(self,flowable):

    if hasattr(flowable, 'cReport'):

        cReport = getattr(flowable, 'cReport')
        self.cReport = cReport
```

Then while adding data for the r1 report a custom attribute will be created

```
elements.append(PageBreak())
elements[-1].cReport = 'r1'
```

Same code while adding data for r2 report

```
elements.append(PageBreak())
elements[-1].cReport = 'r2'
```

Then in the onPage function of the template

```
template = PageTemplate(id='test', frames=frame, onPage=headerAndFooter)

def headerAndFooter(canvas, doc):

        canvas.saveState()

        if cReport == 'r1':
            Ph = Paragraph("""<para>r1 Report (continued)</para>""",styleH5)
            w, h = Ph.wrap(doc.width, doc.topMargin)
            Ph.drawOn(canvas, doc.leftMargin, doc.height+doc.topMargin)
```

Note that i'm just copy and pasting parts of my code...